# Apache Tika Server issue and unable to read a PDF file

Tags: python-3.x, apache-tika

I am trying to just read in the data from Apache tika library to parse the pdf files. I installed it through `pip install tika` using python 3.

Code:

```
from tika import parser
parsedPDF = parser.from_file("test.pdf",serverEndpoint='http://localhost:9998')
```

or

```
from tika import parser
parsedPDF = parser.from_file("test.pdf")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tikaparsing-test.py", line 2, in <module>
    parsedPDF = parser.from_file("test.pdf",serverEndpoint='http://localhost:9998')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tika\parser.py", line 36, in from_file
    jsonOutput = parse1('all', filename, serverEndpoint, headers=headers)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tika\tika.py", line 316, in parse1
    headers, verbose, tikaServerJar, rawResponse=rawResponse)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tika\tika.py", line 510, in callServer
    serverEndpoint = checkTikaServer(scheme, serverHost, port, tikaServerJar, classpath)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tika\tika.py", line 565, in checkTikaServer
    startServer(jarPath, serverHost, port, classpath)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tika\tika.py", line 609, in startServer
    cmd = Popen(cmd , stdout= logFile, stderr = STDOUT, shell =True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

Comment: Do you have write permissions to the PDF in question? Have you made sure the PDF isn't already open in something else?

Comment: Nothing is open and still the same problem. I have no problem accessing those files .py from the error above

Comment: What about the input pdf though?